# Visualizar Imagenes guardadas en un servidor remoto en un cliente Java

Tags: java, java-swing, servicio

Tengo que crear una aplicación Java con interfaz grafica cliente-servidor remoto, que permita al cliente visualizar una imagen guardada en un servidor remoto(mi pc), no quiero salvar la imagen , solo visualizarla desde un JPanel o algo parecido.

Es posible esto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ahora mismo me imagino tres opciones:

1. Tener en el servidor remoto una base de datos que almacene las imágenes.
2. Leer las imágenes por medio de socket.
3. Tener las imágenes en un CDN.

---

#### Base de datos remota

La manera de conectarte es como si lo hicieras en local. Supongamos tu IP es `200.45.175.34` y el puerto `5896`.

```
private static final String HOST = "200.45.175.34";
private static final String PORT = 5896;
private static final String DATABASE = "bdremota";
private static final String URL = "jdbc:mysql://" + HOST 
                                    + ":" + PORT 
                                    + "/" + DATABASE;

try {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(URL);
} catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {
    // hacer algo
}
```

Y para obtener una determinada imagen puedes hacerlo por medio del `UID` de la imagen:

```
public Optional<ImageIcon> readImage(uid) {
    String sql = "SELECT bin_data FROM imagenes WHERE uid = ?";
    try (Connection conn = ConnectionHelper.getConnection();
         PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql) {
        pst.setString(1, uid); // el uid de la imagen a leer
        ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
        ImageIcon icon = null;
        if(rs.next()) {
            byte[] image = IOUtils.toByteArray(rs.getBinaryStream());
            icon = new ImageIcon(image);
        }
        return Optinal.of(icon);
    } catch(SQLException e) {
        // hacer algo
        return Optional.empty();
    }
}

Optional<ImageIcon> oIcon = Clase.readImage("10383");
// si la imagen existe
if(oIcon.isPresent()) {
    // mostrarla en el JPanel
}
```

#### Por medio de Socket

```
clientSocket = new Socket("localhost", 6002);
outputStream = clientSocket.getOutputStream();
dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(outputStream);
inputStream = clientSocket.getInputStream();

// mandamos el uid
dataOutputStream.writeUTF("1458");

// y el servidor nos devuelve la imagen
byte[] bufferSize = new byte[4096];
inputStream.read(bufferSize);
int size = ByteBuffer.wrap(buffeSize).asIntBuffer().get();
byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
inputStream.read(buffer);

// convertimos el InputStream a byte[] para pasarlo a ImageIcon
byte[] binaryImage = new ByteArrayInputStream(buffer).toByteArray();
return new ImageIcon(binaryImage);
```

#### Por medio de CDN

Busca algún servidor CDN de imágenes que tenga una API sencilla y úsalo. Una opción es [Cloudinary](http://cloudinary.com/)

Comment: Hola, gracias por tus respuestas yo estoy usando postgresSQL para almacenar del tipo password e id , nose si sea cierto pero e leido que usando las imagenes como ImageIcon estas tienen baja resolucion .En fin probare y vere cual me resulta mejor .

Answer (score 0):

**Respuesta corta:** Si

**Respuesta larga:**
Hace tiempo tuve que hacer algo parecido.

La única solución "estable" que encontré fue hacer un servidor java de imágenes (se alojaba en mi PC o en el PC que quisieras), que se encargaba de leer peticiones de un puerto y enviar las imágenes que le pedían.

Es decir, el cliente se conectaba y pedía la lista de imágenes, el servidor le daba la lista de imágenes que disponía y el cliente a partir de ahí le iba pidiendo imágenes.

Esto funcionaba en red local, con Internet por el medio no lo tengo muy claro si te iría bien.

Si te tiene que ir por Internet creo que sería mejor opción subir las imágenes a Picasa o imgur o algún servidor parecido y bajártelas desde la aplicación que hagas.

Seguramente la opción que tomé yo actualmente no es la mejor, pero a mi me funcionó.